# A directory created in my web application running inside docker is missing

Tags: python, docker, flask, django-forms, docker-compose

I have created a web application to upload image files using Django and Flask which is deployed in docker. However, the directory which i create to store the uploaded files are missing in my container.

```
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Nov/2016 14:27:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200/app/images/
[<FileStorage: u'image_7.png' ('image/png')>]
<FileStorage: u'image_7.png' ('image/png')>
image_7.png is the file name
('Accept incoming file:', u'image_7.png')
('Save it to:', u'/app/images//image_7.png')
/app/images/image_7.png
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:273:     
UserWarning: Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.
warnings.warn('Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.')
(149, 250, 4)
```

In the log file above, you can see **/app/images/** it is the directory my app creates and in that I store uploaded images.

The python code I used to upload:

```
        target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'images/')
        print(target)
        if not os.path.isdir(target):
                os.mkdir(target)
        else:
            print("Couldn't create upload directory: {}".format(target))
        print(request.files.getlist("file"))
        for upload in request.files.getlist("file"):
            print(upload)
            print("{} is the file name".format(upload.filename))
            filename = upload.filename
            destination = "/".join([target, filename])
            print ("Accept incoming file:", filename)
            print ("Save it to:", destination)
            upload.save(destination)
```

This is my Dockerfile structure:

```
  ├── Dockerfile
  ├── app
  │   ├── app.py
  │   ├── index.csv
  │   ├── pyimagesearch
  │   │   ├── __init__.py
  │   │   ├── colordescriptor.py
  │   │   └── searcher.py
  |   ├── **images**(this folder is missing) 
  │   ├── static
  │   │   ├── main.css
  │   │   └── main.js
  │   └── templates
  │       ├── _base.html
  │       └── index.html
  ├── config
  │   ├── app.ini
  │   ├── nginx.conf
  │   └── supervisor.conf
  └── requirements.txt
```

Can anyone tell me, how to make this **images** directory and files stored in it visible?

Note: If I run this app without docker, then the Image directory is visible.

Comment: How many containers do you have ? It seems to me you have one container for the web server, and one from which you are uploading. 
can you make it clear ?

Comment: Yes you are correct, I just have only one container.

Comment: @Xenwar you can find my dockerfile structure above....app.py is the main file.

Comment: Perhaps, my question was not clear. Check this link https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/
. You need to identify which container is the client. If not, use data volumes to share the image folder.

Comment: @Xenwar could you please tell me how to use data volumes...I am new to docker.

Comment: ok. have added a new answer.

Comment: the new answer is removed.